# Why are POSIXlt dates changed when converting a list into a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, posixlt

I have these lines of an R-script:

```
date1999 = as.POSIXlt("1999-01-01", tz = "Etc/GMT-1")
date2001 = as.POSIXlt("2001-01-01", tz = "Etc/GMT-1")
dates=c(date1999, date2001)
print(hours(dates)) # -> [1] 0 0
l=list(dates=dates)
print(hours(l$dates)) # -> [1] 0 0
d=as.data.frame(l)
print(hours(d$dates)) # -> [1] 23 23
```

I find this kind of weird and can't figure out why this happens (this doesn't occur when using Date instead of POSIXlt).

Can somebody explain this? Or comment on whether I do something strange in the Date definition? Thanks already!

Comment: Where's `hours()` from?

Comment: The lt form is a list of same-length vectors, it gets treated as a data frame with a column for each element. Don't use it, cast to POSIXct to use as a single column. Or use lubridate if you can stomach the name.

Comment: hours() is from from package "chron"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Lubridate looks interesting, I might give it a try next time. For now I decided to solve it quick and dirty by setting the hours to 0 again explicitely.

Comment: No, use `POSIXct` as advised by @mdsumner. There is no advantage, but some potential problems in using `POSIXlt`.

Comment: It is a pointless class, today, it could be used on the fly to get individual component values, all hidden by easy wrappers. (Probably that is what lubridate does)